# Start/Stop Windows Service with Flutter/Dart

Tags: windows, flutter, powershell, dart, cmd

I would like to know if there is any way to stop/start a windows service with flutter/dart.

I intend to develop an windows application to assist in the ERP deployment. In some cases I need to restart the service after changing the configuration.

Comment: Is this a PowerShell question or a flutter/dart question?